# How to prevent first post and first comment on WP MU?

Tags: multisite, customization, installation

When a user creates a new blog a new post and a new comment is created at the same time. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually just run a function on **wpmu_new_blog** - best to put in **mu-plugins**

```
function wpse_wpmu_remove_default_content($blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta) {

  if ( !current_user_can('manage_network') )
    return;

  switch_to_blog($blog_id);

  // Remove the default post & page
  wp_delete_post(1, true);
  wp_delete_post(2, true);

  // Remove the first comment
  wp_delete_comment( 1, true );

  restore_current_blog();
}

add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'wpse_wpmu_remove_default_content' );
```

Comment: Tried to add a semicolon after wp_delete_comment line but it says I can't make edits less than 6 characters. The all knowing StackExchange gods know that nothing less than 6 characters could be useful.

Comment: I've done that, cheers for the spot.

Comment: Nice, thanks for this. Btw, there's a ':' after `restore_current_blog()` instead of ';'. Just FYI. (1 char edit...)

Comment: Where would this file be? I can't find it.